# jQuery length returns zero when trying to count divs

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Ways I can be contacted</legend>
    <div class="error-message-list"></div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="row">
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>                
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p><a id="count" href="#">Couynt</a></p>
```

..and here's my Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on({
            click: function(event) { 
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log($(this).parents().siblings('fieldset .rows div.row').length);
            }
        },'#count');
    </script>
```

When I click on "Count" a zero gets written to the console. I would expect this to be a 2 because there are 2 divs with the class of `row` within the `rows` div.

If I just do it on the fieldset, ie, like this:

```
console.log($(this).parents().siblings('fieldset').length);
```

Then it returns a 1 as I would expect.

I have also tried

```
console.log($(this).parents().siblings('fieldset .rows .row').length);
```

and

```
console.log($(this).parents().siblings('fieldset > div.rows > div.row').length);
```

..and many other combinations, but I just can't get it to say '2'!

Comment: why not to use `$('fieldset .rows div.row').length` ?

Comment: @Cherniv There is more than one <fieldset> on the page and I want to be able to re-use the same snippet of JQuery code for all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand how [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) work.

```
.siblings('fieldset .rows div.row')
```

will select all siblings that match the selector, i.e. elements that are `div`s with class `row` and that are descendants of `.rows` and `fieldset` elements.

The only sibling of the `p` element is a `fieldset` element though, which is certainly not a `div`.

You can use `.find`, to select the elements *inside* the `fieldset` sibling. For example:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('fieldset').find('.rows div.row').length
```

There are many ways to traverse/select the DOM to get the information you want. For example:

```
$(this).closest('p').prev('fieldset').find('div.row').length
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I get it now. Thank you for the detailed explanation! I'll mark this as the correct answer in a minute when SO lets me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

DEMO `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/EHYyk/

```
$(document).on({
            click: function(event) { 
               event.preventDefault();
                console.log($('fieldset .rows .row').length);
            }
        },'#count');
```

[**`siblings()`**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) will give you the adjacent elements, you can directly traverse to the `.row` class.

Comment: @Dando Jerry - Yes, that works if there is only one fieldset on the page, but I have a few (sorry, I didn't mention this in my original question). So, I need to do it using $(this). The above answer from Felix does this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try less code, http://jsfiddle.net/2PpGN/

```
var c = $(".rows").children(".row").length;
alert(c)
```